# Redirect a request to specific action in controller inside public F.Promise<SimpleResult> call(Http.Context ctx){}

Tags: java, http, url, redirect, playframework-2.2

I am using play 2.2.x and I am working on a project.I want to check if admin is in session before some actions(methods) defined in my AdminController class.So if a user is not logged in and try enter adminpage url in browser he should be redirected to a specific page say login.scala.html.

**my code** ([Source](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaActionsComposition))

```
 public F.Promise<SimpleResult> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {

        if (check if user is in session) {

              return delegate.call(ctx);
        } else {

            return redirect(routes.AdminController.login());
        }
    }
```

but the above code gives me an **incompatible types** compilation error.

So how can I redirect url?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `redirect` call does not return a `F.Promise`, hence the type error. You can wrap the redirect call with `pure`:

```
public F.Promise<SimpleResult> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
    if (/* your condition */) {
       return delegate.call(ctx);
    } else {
       return F.Promise.pure(redirect(routes.AdminController.login()));
    }
}
```